# Richfaces popup disappearing when clicked on the dropdown menu item

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I need to display the context menu when clicked on a rich:dataTable column,and need to show a rich:popupPanel when clicked on a menu item. I could able to get the popup but it is disappearing instantly.Does anyone have an idea on this?

I am using rich:dropDownMenu (RichFaces 4.0.0.Final).

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a  domElementAttachment="parent" in your popup, than change it to  domElementAttachment="form". If you still have the problem I can insert the full code here.